# Adding weights to edges in networkx automatically depending of the number of connections form pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am trying to create out of a pandas dataframe a directed graph right now with networkx, so far i can use:

```
nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Activity', 'Activity followed', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

which shows me all the nodes and edges from Activity --> Activity followed.

In my dataframe there is sometimes the same activity followed by the same activity and i want to count this number in form of weights for the edges so far example this is my dataframe:

```
Index Activity Activityfollowed
0     Lunch    Dinner
1     Lunch    Dinner
2     Breakfast Lunch
```

should have the Edges:

Lunch --> Dinner (weight 2)

Breakfast --> Lunch (weight 1)

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: please include a sample of your data

Comment: see the dataframe above

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try adding the `weight` attribute as a column, using [`groupby.transform`](http://OutEdgeDataView([('Lunch',%20'Dinner',%20%7B'weight':%202%7D),%20('Breakfast',%20'Lunch',%20%7B'weight':%201%7D)])), then pass the `edge_attr` argument to the `from_pandas_edgelist` method:

```
df['weight'] = df.groupby(['Activity', 'Activityfollowed'])['Activity'].transform('size')

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Activity', 'Activityfollowed',
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph(), edge_attr='weight')
```

Confirm that it's worked using:

```
G.edges(data=True)
```

[out]

```
OutEdgeDataView([('Lunch', 'Dinner', {'weight': 2}), ('Breakfast', 'Lunch', {'weight': 1})])
```